# JSON data in sectionedTableView iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, json, uitableview

I recieve customer data from my mysql database. I would like to show all customers in a sectioned table view. the title of each section is the first letter of the customer name and the numberOfrows in each section is the count of customers beginning with the same letter. Basically it should look like my contact app on my iPhone.

here is my data http://mobile.beger.org/getdata.php53?object=customer&mode=all

right now i can show all customers in my tableView. How can i put the customers in sections? 
do i have to edit my mysql select? Or should i have two json strings. One with each letter and the count of customers starting with this letter and the other one with the customer details?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are use this kind of block for the easy and cheap solution. I have edit you web service response. Please take a look.

```
{
  "customer": [
    { "A": [
      {
        "i_customer_m": "22",
        "s_name1": "Amann Solutions AG",
        "s_town": "Herisau"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "5",
        "s_name1": "Architekturhaus Leibold GmbH",
        "s_town": "D\u00fcnkelsried"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "68",
        "s_name1": "ATEcare Service GmbH & Co.KG",
        "s_town": "Aichach"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "83",
        "s_name1": "Autohandel Polska GmbH",
        "s_town": "Prag"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "65",
        "s_name1": "Autohandel Polska GmbH",
        "s_town": "Prag"
      }
    ]},
    {"B": [
      {
        "i_customer_m": "45",
        "s_name1": "Baugenossenschaft Strassbourgh",
        "s_town": "Strassbourgh"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "11",
        "s_name1": "Baugenossenschaft Wien",
        "s_town": "Wien"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "1",
        "s_name1": "Betzy AG",
        "s_town": "Germering, Oberbayern"
      },
      {
        "i_customer_m": "46",
        "s_name1": "BSG",
        "s_town": "Herrsching am Ammersee"
      },
      {
        "FirstLetter": "B",
        "i_customer_m": "67",
        "s_name1": "BVVS Systemhaus GmbH",
        "s_town": "M\u00fcnchen"
      }
    ]}
  ]
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: From this we also reduce the data redundancy. And get quicker response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
So how do have to change my mysql/php code to make it look like yours? here it is
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(CUSTOMER_M.s_name1,1) as FirstLetter,CUSTOMER_M.i_customer_m, CUSTOMER_M.s_name1, COALESCE(CUSTOMER_M.s_town,'unbekannt') as s_town FROM `CUSTOMER_M` WHERE CUSTOMER_M.I_CUSTOMER_M > 0 ORDER BY CUSTOMER_M.S_NAME1");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    
   $arr[] = $obj;
   }

echo '{"customer":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

Comment: Format the JSON as code (highlight it and press the `{}` button).  That way the formatting is preserved (I did it for you already on this occasion).

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) i would love to do it, but i can answer my own question. and in the comment box, i cant use the code {} function!

Comment: i checked the json code from above. it is not valid? i do unterstand what it should do, but it doesnt.